# SharePoint Keyword Query Search In SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I want to get all pages from pages library from search result where page layout name is "abc.aspx". I have tried below code but it is not working. If I simply pass "abc" in querytext then it will get result from list,library and from every where. I want to get only those pages whose page layout is "abc.aspx". How to do that?

```
string pageLayoutFullName="abc.aspx"
  KeywordQuery keywordQueryTop = new KeywordQuery(site);
  keywordQueryTop.SelectProperties.Add("Title");
  keywordQueryTop.SelectProperties.Add("PublishingPageLayoutOWSURLH");
  keywordQueryTop.SelectProperties.Add("WebId");
  keywordQueryTop.SelectProperties.Add("ModifiedOWSDATE");
  keywordQueryTop.RowLimit = 15;
  keywordQueryTop.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.SharepointSearch;
  keywordQueryTop.QueryText = String.Format("PublishingPageLayoutOWSURLH=\"*{0}\"", pageLayoutFullName);
```

Comment: The problem you have is because SharePoint search does not support suffix-matching (`*omething`), only prefix-matching (`somethin*`). Try to add the full URL to the page layout, or look for another managed property containing only for examle the name of the layout

Comment: I could not find another useful managed propery for you unfortunately. Are the pages from only one site collection? Then you can use the full path `http://portal.com/_catalogs/masterpage/PageLayoutFileName.aspx, PageLayoutName`. If not, it seems more difficult!

Comment: Another approach would be to use a unique content type for this page layout - then instead of querying for page layout name you could query for content type which will work just fine.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822368(v=office.15).aspx#UnderstandingPageFields

Comment: Yupp, the content type approach seems to be the only viable one in this scenario (as mentioned last in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is because SharePoint search does not support suffix-matching (`*omething`), only prefix-matching (`somethin*`). Therefore this row will not work

```
keywordQueryTop.QueryText = String.Format("PublishingPageLayoutOWSURLH=\"*{0}\"", pageLayoutFullName);
```

Are the pages from only one site collection? Then you can use the full path `http://portal.com/_catalogs/masterpage/PageLayoutFileName.aspx, PageLayoutName`.

If not, it seems more difficult!

There is a crawled property named "ows_PublishingPageLayout", try mapping that one up to a [new Managed Property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667(v=office.15).aspx#proc2), perform a full crawl and see what you get from that property (you can use the REST API in the browser to test it:

```
http://portal.com/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&selectproperties='PublishingPageLayout'
```

**Update**

Unfortunately, this property also indexes the URL, not the name:

```
<d:Key>PublishingPageLayout</d:Key> 
<d:Value>http://portal.com/_catalogs/masterpage/PageLayoutFileName.aspx</d:Value>
```

which is not helpful for you. I find no other properties that seems to be useful, so you might be out of luck I'm afraid (if the specific Page Layout does not use a specific custom content type).

Comment: In one web application I have have page layout and pages. Pages are also in variance site in English and German.

Comment: In one web application I have page layout and pages. Pages are also in variance site in English and German. In another web application I have to display that result  from search.Now I can not pass complete URL.

Comment: Are the page layout using a custom content type, or containing some field specific for this page layout? I think that is your only way around

Comment: Page layout is using custom content type

Comment: But from one content type multiple page layout is created.